# Are rotation matrices faithful representations of the rotation group?

Tags: group-theory, rotation, representation-theory, group-representations

I would like to use rotation matrices as representations of the rotation group.  I would like to know if these representations are faithful, i.e. isomorphic to the rotational group elements.

I read on the bottom of p. 61 in Ref. 1 that

> "Only the $j = 1$ representation is isomorphic to the rotation group itself."

Can someone explain to my why this is the case?

Note: $j=1$ means that the eigenvalue of $J^2$ is $j(j+1)$, where $J^2=J_x^2+J_y^2+J_z^2$, where $J_i$ is the generator of rotation about the $i$-axis.

References:

1. J. Tseng, *Symmetry and Relativity,* lecture notes, 2017. The PDF file is available [here](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~tseng/teaching/b2/b2-lectures.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a non-negative integer $j\in\mathbb{N}_0$, the spin-$j$ [group representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation)/homomorphism $$\rho: SO(3)~\to~ GL(2j+1,\mathbb{R}) $$

is [faithful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faithful_representation)/injective iff $j>0$, but technically speaking, never a group isomorphism, since it is never surjective, $${\rm Im}(\rho)~\subsetneq~ GL(2j+1,\mathbb{R}) .$$

Comment: Is the quotation from my textbook incorrect?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are, in the sense that 
$$
R(\Omega_1)\cdot R(\Omega_2)= R(\Omega_1\cdot \Omega_2)
\Rightarrow \sum_m D^{j}_{m_1m}(\Omega_1)D^j_{mm_2}(\Omega_2)
=D^j_{m_1m_2}(\Omega_1\cdot \Omega_2)
$$
valid for any $j$,
although of course finding analytically $\Omega_1\cdot\Omega_2$ in terms of the triples of parameters $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ is usually messy.

The case $j=1$ is the defining representation so the matrices you get are identical as those obtained by geometrically constructing rotations in 3-space.  (Usually the $D$’s are in a spherical basis so you need to consider combinations of $\hat x\pm i\hat y$ as basis vectors.

One way to understand why this is true is that the rotation matrices are exponentials of the algebra $\{J_x,J_y,J_z\}$, that the a faithful representation of the algebra by $(2j+1)\times (2j+1)$ matrices will also exponentiate to a faithful representation (of the same dimension) of the group.

Comment: I also read that it is not faithful for j=/=1?  Why is it the case?

Comment: I have no idea.